# Undefined symbol "php_libxml_disable_entity_loader"

Tags: freebsd, php, soap

I have php5.4 installed.It runs on freebsd server 
I also use soap.so extension. But when I start php script (`new SoapClient`) it stopped.

```
Apache logs:
tail -f /var/log/httpd-errors.log :
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1: /usr/local/lib/php/20100525/soap.so: Undefined symbol "php_libxml_disable_entity_loader"
```

I tried reinstall php5-extensions after portupgrade

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and it disappeared after upgrading all packages to latest versions.

I believe it was caused by version mismatch between packages (I installed php-soap later, so it was more recent version).

Comment: "I installed php-soap later". Me too. 
 I had `portsnap update` and reinstall `php-extensions`.